# flutter facebook ads how to show?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Hello I use this plugin https://pub.dev/packages/facebook_audience_network for Facebook ads but I don't know how to use when i click on my button then 1st open ads after ad closed it will be going to next page

```
child: InkWell(
                      onTap: () => navigateToDetail(snapshot.data[index]),
                      // Function is executed on tap.)
```

This is my code how I can use 2 events for button click means I will be opened 1st ad after its go to next page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create Future class to navigate the 1st ads, and use (Then method) to start next page.

```
Future<void> newFuture (var data) async{
   navigateToDetail(snapshot.data[index])
   .then((value) => 'put the other function'(value));
   }
```

see this tutorial for more info : https://medium.com/dartlang/dart-asynchronous-programming-futures-96937f831137